# mysql - use result of query in multiple sub queries

Tags: mysql, subquery

To describe my problem, heres a hypothetical scenario:

```
(
    select user_id, stat
    from stats1
    where user_id in (select id from users where selected = 1)
)

union

(
    select user_id, stat
    from stats2
    where user_id in (select id from users where selected = 1)
)
union
(
    select user_id, stat
    from stats3
    where user_id in (select id from users where selected = 1)
)
# and so on ...
```

see how the query in 'where in' is used multiple times. I want to save the result of this query adn then use it. in all the other queries. Obviously this is easily possible if by running that query in PHP and then passing in the values, but is this possible purely in MySQL?

Comment: I think you could use some [MySQL view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-syntax.html). I assume that the engine will use the cache during the request after the first request

Comment: You can store the result of that query in a mysql variable and later you can refer to it.

Comment: This is usually done with CTEs something that's missing in mysql and mysql is very slow with these sort of subqueries. Why do you need it? Shouldn't statsN be just one table instead of several?

Comment: why you have multiple tables with the same structure? I would use one table stats with a stats_number column, then you won't need to use a union query and the in (...) subquery won't need to be repeated

Comment: @fthiella is right! With a better architecture and some indexes, you could have only one table and some easier queries! Furthermore, with you current structure you have to create a new table each time you need to add a new stat...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a permanent view for your selected users

```
CREATE VIEW selectedUsers AS SELECT id FROM users WHERE selected = 1;
```

Then when you need it, your syntax will be easier and lighter

```
(
    SELECT user_id, stat
    FROM stats1
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT * FROM selectedUsers)
)

UNION

(
    SELECT user_id, stat
    from stats2
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT * FROM selectedUsers)
)
UNION
(
    SELECT user_id, stat
    FROM stats3
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT * FROM selectedUsers)
)
# and so on ...
```

If your data in the table *users* doesn't change during the request, the database engine should use the cache each time your view is needed

Here is the [MySQL Views documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-syntax.html)

Comment: shouldn't that be user_id IN (Select * from selectedUsers) ?

Comment: @Ahmed-Anas Ok for you?